# Adult talking in Peanuts

Tags: analysis, production, sound-effects, peanuts

I have always wondered: why do adults in *Peanuts* not really talk?

Why do they only make that *wah wah wah* noise? (By the way, what was it? That sounds like a trombone or a trumpet with a mute.)

Comment: Is this about the *Peanuts* movie specifically or about the whole of *Peanuts*?

Comment: @NapoleonWilson It's about the whole of *Peanuts*.

Comment: I always thought that it was because of the way that kids heard adults.  Whenever adults are speaking kids just hear "wah wah wah"

Comment: @steelerfan but did you think that because of Peanuts or did Peanuts do it cause that's what we think? *mind blown*

Comment: @cde Well, when I got older, I always thought that's why the adults talked that way.  I guess It's what I think and Peanuts read my mind ;)

Comment: I remember being about the same age as Charlie Brown and wondering about this. It was really weird and confusing especially since Charlie Brown clearly understood the garbled speach perfectly.

Comment: In the whole Peanuts comics, adults are never shown and never heard. You must be talking about the movies only.

Comment: @edc65 Yes the movies only. But I think Napoleon Wilson was talking about the movie that was released last year: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Peanuts_Movie I am talking about all the movies (released from the 70s to the 80s)

Comment: @edc65: There was a peanuts comic which featured adult dialog. Linus was discussing 'knowing the adult mind'. Linus asked Sally to ask one of their parents "Why is there fathers' day and mothers' day, but no childrens' day", and he correctly predicted the adult response "Every day is childrens' day". The adult response appeared in text, from an unseen outside source. I can't find the strip online, but a quote from it is here: http://people.cs.uchicago.edu/~dinoj/peanuts.html

Comment: A very similar comic is here: http://www.gocomics.com/peanuts/2013/09/15  Also along the 'know the adult mind theme'. The grandma's voice is shown.

Comment: Maybe it's the flip-side of the old adage "Children should be seen but not heard". Perhaps from a child's perspective, it's the other way around.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

> Television producer Lee Mendelson was already a few years into his
> collaboration with Peanuts creator Charles Schulz when he was faced
> with an unusual problem: How do you depict adults in an animated
> special for a comic strip that never features adults?
>
> Mendelson told Mashable, “We chose not to show the adult. So I asked
> our music director, Vince Guaraldi, ‘Would there be some instrument we
> could use as a sound to emulate what an adult might sound like to a
> kid?’”
>
> Guaraldi, who first collaborated with Schulz and Mendelson on a 1963
> documentary about the comic strip legend, didn’t hesitate. He brought
> in a trombone player. ([mashable)](http://mashable.com/2015/10/26/peanuts-wah-wah/#59GaHeW9Q8q4)

Comment: For the sake of completeness, you may want to add that it was created by speaking lines into a trombone with a mute that was opened and closed.

Comment: @alex_d - Agreed. Admittedly, the mute was obvious (well, to anyone who's ever heard a muted horn live anyway). What I wasn't sure about was what kind of horn was used.

Comment: It may be worth mentioning that in a comic strip the reader can fill in what the adult would presumably have said, but a television show or movie will need to do *something* to fill in the time.  Silence would suggest that nobody is speaking (which isn't true), so the noise is used to indicate that someone is speaking but it doesn't matter what they're saying.  BTW, Charlie Chaplin's movie *City Lights* used a kazoo for IIRC a mayor's speech, for similar reasons.

Answer (score 6):

I know that this is a question posted regarding the TV Show and, potentially, the recent movie but in regards to adults in Schulz work, the [Peanuts Wiki](http://peanuts.wikia.com/wiki/Adults) site states:

> Schulz said that grown-ups just did not interest him. The absence of
>   adults also gives Peanuts a unique point of view, bringing the comic
>   down to the level of children, and not children from an adult's
>   viewpoint.

A few years or so ago I wondered this same question.  I can't recall where but I do seem to recall that I managed to find a reasonably reliable or "official" source expressing these thoughts nearly verbatim.  Likewise, you can find similar mentioning's of Schulz perspective on adults in his strips throughout the web.

The bottomline from what I've gathered in my research is that having adults express themselves within his comics would have provided a form of "noise" that would have detracted from the many *adult* moments that were being communicated through the experiences of the children within the strip.  Peanuts resinates with so many people because through the simplicity of children, we often experience very deep and emotional observations of life, ourselves and others.

If this was legitimately Schulz intent then having adult dialog would have degraded the essence of the messages he was trying to express.